# Batch Error: “< was not expected at this time”

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command

I want to use Ptexport to get info from a http server, but i cant seen to type the right syntaxis.

I have tried differente types of syntaxis.

```
wget.exe --user=export_kpi --password=kpi123 -O Result3.txt http://XX.YYY.CCC.BB/export/Export?req='<Ptexport version="1.6.0"><Request><ResultReq egname="test_kpi" templRR1="kpi_lost">'**
```

and i get this

< was not expected

I should get on the .txt something like this:

```
cat Result3.txt |sed 's/></>\n</g'
<Ptexport version="1.6.0" >
<Response>
<RR cid="1459546492000" sid="33966" eod="0">
<RR1 direction="0" statTime="1552888534574" dmax="400" />
<RR1 direction="1" statTime="1552888534574" dmax="413" />
<RR1 direction="0" statTime="1552888594575" dmax="466" />
<RR1 direction="1" statTime="1552888594575" dmax="487" />
<RR1 direction="0" statTime="1552888654575" dmax="371" />
<RR1 direction="1" statTime="1552888654575" dmax="427" />
</RR>
<RR cid="1459546492000" sid="33968" eod="0">
..etc
```

Comment: Neither from your tags nor from your commands it's clear what environment you are using. In cmd.exe the chars `<>|&` have to either be escaped with a caret `^` or be enclosed in double quotes. In windows wget,cat and sed aren't available by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put a literal `<` in your URL. Use `%3C` instead.

See [here for a list of escape codes in a URL](https://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html)

Comment: from the beggining in the result i got:    

Connecting to 10.114.245.98:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your url in double quotes like below

```
wget.exe --user=export_kpi --password=kpi123 -O Result3.txt "http://XX.YYY.CCC.BB/export/Export?req='<Ptexport version=,\"1.6.0\"><Request><ResultReq egname=\"test_kpi\" templRR1=\"kpi_lost\">'**"
```

Comment: from the beggining in the result i got:    

Connecting to 10.114.245.98:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized